# Django - Isn't there a way to connect a foreign key to a primary key of which datatype isn't integer?

Tags: django, types, model, foreign-keys

```
class Commentor(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, primary_key=True)
    ...

class Comments(models.Model):
    ...
    commentor = models.ForeignKey(Commentor)
```

Above is a part of my code.

As you see, if Django model reflects my intention well, commentor attribute of Comments should be like 'commentor_email' of which datatype is string. But the result is 'commentor_id' of which datatype is integer.

What should I do to enforce the foreign key attribute to follow settings of the Commentor.email attribute?

Comment: Django version you are using ??

Comment: When I type django.VERSION on Python prompt, it shows me  (1, 10, 3, 'final', 0).

Comment: Okay Wait for the answer.

Comment: Ah, datatype problem is solved by recreating db file... But the name is still commentor_id not commentor_email

Comment: Change the name of field as this with db_column: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#db-column

Comment: Then it makes the name as db_colum_id, not db_column. :)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your word. I added a field db_column and the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: use `commentor_pk` instead of `commentor_id`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [to_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) , `email` must be `unique=True`:

```
class Commentor(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    ...

class Comments(models.Model):
    ...
    commentor = models.ForeignKey(Commentor, to_field='email')
```

Comment: Since `email` is the primary key of `Commentor`, this has absolutely no effect. By default a `ForeignKey` always points to the primary key. `unique=True` is redundant as well.